# How to use valid_file_mimetypes, valid_image_mimetypes correctly?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to use valid_file_mimetypes, valid_image_mimetypes to validate file that in config/lfm.php. 
valid_file_mimetypes:

```
'valid_image_mimetypes' => [
    'image/jpeg',
    'image/pjpeg',
    'image/png',
    'image/gif',
    'image/svg+xml',
],

'valid_file_mimetypes' => [
        'image/jpeg',
        'image/pjpeg',
        'image/png',
        'image/gif',
        'image/svg+xml',
        'application/pdf',
        'application/rtf',
        'application/vnd',
        'application/msword',
        'application/vnd.ms-excel',
        'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint',
        'application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text',
        'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
        'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document',
        'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation',
        'text/plain',
    ];
```

I take them and rewrote. It is my code:

```
protected function getValidatorMimes($field)
{
    $mimes = [];

    foreach (config('lfm.' . 'valid_' . $field . '_mimetypes') as $mime) {
        $mimes[] = explode('/', $mime)[1];
    }

    return 'mimes:' . implode(',', $mimes);
}
```

the function will return this, for example:

```
'mimes:jpeg,pjpeg,png,gif,svg+xml,pdf,rtf,vnd,msword,vnd.ms-excel,vnd.ms-powerpoint,vnd.oasis.opendocument.text,vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet,vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document,officedocument.presentationml.presentation,plain'
```

and I use it on validate.

```
$rules = [];
foreach ($fields as $field) {
    $rules[$field] = $this->getValidatorMimes($field);
}

$validator = Validator::make(Request::all(), $rules);
```

But this validation does not skip a single file.

Is my valdation rule correct? Please help me? I do not know how to use mimetypes correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It was so easy to solve the problem. I was just not looking enough. 
In this case, instead of "mimes:" i just had to "mimetypes:".

```
protected function getValidatorMimes($field)
{
    $mimes = [];

    foreach (config('lfm.' . 'valid_' . $field . '_mimetypes') as $mime) {
        $mimes[] = explode('/', $mime)[1];
    }

    return 'mimetypes:' . implode(',', $mimes);
}
```